# Inno Setup sets new subkey in Registry

Tags: registry, inno-setup

i try to set a key in the registry by using inno setup.
but it always set the entry in a new subkey section.

i want to add the data in ...\Wow6432Node\, that means it should be a new sub in that folder, but i always get in ...\Wow6432Node... a new \Wow6432Node\ sub and the daa will be written there :(
how can i make it right.
 this is my code:

```
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\{#MyAppPublisher}\{app}; ValueType: string; ValueName: GameExplorer; ValueData: {{503F23A6-47E5-4877-9C15-FFBD8C687878}
```

after install i get this in my registry
 HKLM\SubKey: SOFTWARE****Wow6432Node****Wow6432Node**{#MyAppPublisher}{app}

but i want this
 HKLM\SubKey: SOFTWARE**Wow6432Node**{#MyAppPublisher}{app}

i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because InnoSetup is 32bit, it defaults to writing in the 32 bit portion of the registry (Wow6432Node).  To use the 64 bit portion of the registry, you need to use the "64" delimiter like `HKLM64`.  If the install is running in 64-bit mode, HKLM is equivalent to HKLM64 and to write to the 32 bit portion your entry would specify `HKML32`.
In your case, you need to remove the Wow6432Node from your entry:

```
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\{#MyAppPublisher}\{app}; ValueType: string; ValueName: GameExplorer; ValueData: {{503F23A6-47E5-4877-9C15-FFBD8C687878}
```

Comment: thank you so much. it was exactly whta i did wrong. :)
now it works perfectly .